# How to sort by two conditions in a query function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently, the query in the image is sorting automatically by oldest date to newest. How would I go about sorting with two conditions: oldest date to newest and High Priority score to lowest (oldest to newest date would take priority, and within those dates, priority score would be the second priority for sorting)

The dates are under variable "A" and Priority score is under variable "G" in the named range.

[image: See Here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY(backlogdata, "Select A, D, E, G where A is not null order by A asc, G desc limit "&F1, 1)
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Very nice, I figured it was simple, but couldnt find the correct format.